# Can I Implement a Video Player through Flutter Widget？

Tags: flutter

If I use a Widget to implement the player, will performance be a problem?

I know dart has dart:ffi package, It can process native c/c++ code.
So, can I use it to implement a VideoPlayer with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

It might be slow in debugging mode, after building your app try running in release mode

> Try running your app in release mode using **flutter run --release** in the terminal.

- Package:video_player 0.10.2+1.

Package:video_player 0.10.2+1.
Flutter plugin for displaying inline video with other Flutter widgets on Android and iOS.

Comment: video_player plugin that use android & ios view implement.

Comment: Thank you, Help me fix my grammer mistake.